# how do I combine 2 JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var id = "['1', '2', '3']"

var name = "['a', 'b', 'c']"
```

What i want is to show Json like

[
{
id: '1',
name: 'a'
},
{
id: '2',
name: 'b'
},
{
id: '3',
name: 'c'
}
]

sth like this.

how can i make it like that in Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: Please make an attempt at solving it yourself, or show us what have you tried so far. Hint: You could do this with a simple 'for' loop and match up the ID and Name into a now array like this `yourNewArray[i] = "id: "+id[i]+", name: "+name[i];`, then convert/save it to JSON like normal.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Given the tag of `jquery`, it sounds like you meant JavaScript. If so, fix the tag.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to evaluate the string expressions and convert them to arrays like this:

```
const ids = eval("['1', '2', '3']");
const names = eval("['a', 'b', 'c']");
```

and if the ids and names arrays have the same length, you can do something like this:

```
const result = ids.map((id, index) => ({
    id,
    name: names[index]
}))
```

Comment: Appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1):

- we need to convert id and name variables into object using JSON.parse()
- then combine 2 object into a result object
- parse result object into JSON using JSON.stringify()

```
var id = '["1", "2", "3"]'
var name = '["a", "b", "c"]'

id = JSON.parse(id);
name = JSON.parse(name);

let result = id.map((value, index) => ({
    id: value,
    name: name[index]
}))

result = JSON.stringify(result)
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of another answer.